# How to abstract a JavaScript Function (mixpanel)

Tags: javascript, jquery, mixpanel

I'm working to abstract a mixpanel tracking function. The function workings like this:

```
mixpanel.track("Hello World");
mixpanel.track("Hello World", { "ab_version": 2});
mixpanel.track("Hello World", { "ab_version": 2, "color" : "red"});
```

I'm trying to abstract this so event tracking is not tied to Mixpanel in my application. I've tried doing:

```
MyApp.eventTrack("Hello World", { "ab_version": 2});

(function() {
    MyApp.eventTrack = function(data) {
        mixpanel.track(data);
    }
}());
```

However this is not working properly. Any suggestions how I can make MyApp.eventTrack pass the parameters properly to work with mixpanel.track?

Comment: aren't you missing the second argument in you function definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is missing the second argument:

```
(function() {
    MyApp.eventTrack = function(firstArg, secondArg) {
        mixpanel.track(firstArg, secondArg);
    }
}());
```

Alternatively, you can handle an unbounded number of arguments by using [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) and [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) together:

```
MyApp.eventTrack = function() {
    mixpanel.track.apply(mixpanel, arguments);
}
```

This calls `mixpanel.track` with all arguments passed to `MyApp.eventTrack`.